# Как подключить дебаггер VS Code для front-end проекта со сборкой на gulp?

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code, browsersync

Пробую подключить отладчик VS Code к проекту, который для сборки использует Gulp.

**Симптомы проблемы**
При запуске отладки - точки останова не срабатывают.
Их вид меняется с такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В панели Breakpoints точки останова тоже перестают подсвечиваться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что делаю**

1) Подключаю плагин [Debugger for Chrome - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)

2) Запускаю сборку (c локальным сервером на browsersync с адресом http: //localhost:8080/)

3) Настраиваю конфиг отладчика (файл .vscode/launch.json)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9222"]
        }
    ]
}
```

4) Запускаю отладку - при этом на http://localhost:8080/ корректно открывается index.html проекта

5) Открываю файл http://localhost:8080/page.html со подключенным file.js. Но точки останова не срабатывают.